# "My Facebook post has sunk among all the new posts" Does this sentence sound natural?

Tags: expressions, verbs, social-media

If I posted in some Facebook group and 30 more posts were posted after mine by other members and my post got disappeared, can I say that "My post has sunk among all the new posts"?

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to use "disappeared from the answering block",  "fallen out of the answering block"., or "squeezed out the answering block by the new posts".

Comment: Your post was lost among all the other posts.

Comment: You could still use the sinking metaphor if you said something like "My post **sank without trace** in a tidal wave of new posts"

Comment: @r13 I've never heard anyone use "answering block" when talking about Facebook, and I can't find any relevant examples or definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common, idiomatic phrasing is *got buried*:

- > Are you tired of your Facebook posts getting buried in the news feed? — [How to Improve Your Facebook News Feed Visibility](https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/facebook-news-feed-visibility/)
- > Meanwhile, donkey pages that may not be as trustworthy or relevant with their content may get buried with the updated news feed. — [Here's How to Still See Posts from Your Favorite Pages After Major Changes to Facebook News Feed](https://www.inc.com/larry-kim/heres-how-to-still-see-posts-from-your-favorite-pages-after-major-changes-to-facebook-news-feed.html)
- > [New Posts Getting Buried - Updated, Still A Problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/modhelp/comments/18iup6/new_posts_getting_buried_updated_still_a_problem/)
- > [Instagram is burying new posts under old posts, and I hate it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Instagram/comments/f5k8o2/instagram_is_burying_new_posts_under_old_posts/)

Comment: Thank you, @Laurel